# How to force Eclipse not to format portions of code?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I often use `Ctrl+Shift+F` in Eclipse to format Java source code.

However in some situations I would like that some portions of code were not formatted, e.g. some long CLI commands inside comments.

So, I would like to tell Eclipse: *"whenever I hit `Ctrl+Shift+F`, please format all lines of code except for x-y-z"*.

Is it possible?

Comment: For what language? It matters.

Comment: Sorry! I am talking about Java, I will edit my post.

Comment: I don't think eclipse has "invert selection". Basically you can do it the other way round, just select lines that you need to format then Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: Please elaborate on your question properly and mention your triggering point to get the answer.